# iOS device not showing up on Xamarin drop down

Tags: ios, deployment, xamarin

I am trying to deploy an app written in XS to an iad device. I believe my provisioning profiles are setup correct: http://screencast.com/t/9yEP2CZBWY

In fact, if I go into XS, I can accurately assign the profiles in XS: http://screencast.com/t/U6bH6iubuBsT

However, each time I pull the dropdown for targets, I only see simulators: http://screencast.com/t/5XYsnjTwE9

Please help. I have tried restarting XS numerous times and have tried multiple approaches recommended by Google and SO.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the Build Configuration iPhoneSimulator and iPhone are different Platforms.

I don't have screenshots for Xamarin Studio on Mac handy, but in Visual Studio it's:

- Right-Click on the Project.
- Select properties.
- Select iOS Build.
- Platform Dropdown.
- Select iPhone instead of iPhoneSimulator

Comment: I actually figured this out.  Apparently you have to define separate configurations in XS for iOS device deployment, this is different than when working with Android.